# Wordpress site search functionality is not working because of code in .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have search functionality in my WordPress site. Suddenly it is stopping working. If I check the htaccess file it is adding some extra code by default if I remove that code it is working fine.

Here is the code which it is adding in htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It sounds like you've solved your problem; are you asking for the source of that code?

Comment: i havent solved my problem that was the problem which i am facing

Comment: Are you using some kind of force SSL plugin?

Comment: @HowardE  i am using Yoast SEO

Comment: I don't think yoast I would add that code to your htaccess. If you modify the htaccess manually does it get overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

Change your extra code in .htaccess file to this rule (add it to top of .htaccess file)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

QSA flag means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite.